# C# DataTable.Select With multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, datacolumn

I have a DataTable which I want to query one column at a time to check if it meets the set criteria, for some reason the below code gives correct results for the first column after that the results are incorrect.

```
private bool BusinessRulesOne(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)
    {
        bool isSatisfied = false;
        DataRow[] checkColumn = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " " + "in (1,2,3,)");

        if (checkColumn.Length != 0)
        {
            isSatisfied = true;
        }
        return isSatisfied;
    }
```

On this method Im passing the DataTable I'm querying and DataColumn that I'm currently concentrating on. What needs to happen here is that I want to check if the values on this column consists of the values 1,2 and 3. If yes then return true.

```
 private bool BusinessRulesTwo(DataTable dt, DataColumn dc)
    {
        bool isSatisfied = false;
        var checkColumn = dt.Select(dc.ColumnName + " " + " = 1");

        if (checkColumn.Count() > 3)
        {
            isSatisfied = true;
        }
        return isSatisfied;
    }
```

On the other rule I'm checking if the number of one's (1's) in that column are more than three(3) if yes return true.

Any suggestions are welcome, I'm not clued up with Linq but willing to learn and explore it if it makes life easier.

Comment: Are the column names all ready to use without escape sequences? (No space, no special character, ...). Can you give a small example of exactly what combination of data is giving you the correct / incorrect results? Are the values really a number type and not just a string containing a number character?

Answer (score -1):

Single equals `=` is for assignment, not equality check. Try double equals `== 1` or `equals 1` instead of `= 1`

Comment: Remember this is on `DataTable.Select()` Method so its string or context has to be in a form of SQL query hence I used `=`.